# Using PlayFile apple example with OpenGL freezes OpenGL until playing sound is over

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, audio

I am working on a little app in C++ with Xcode which uses OpenGL. 
I tried to find a way to add simple sounds to my app. I was not too succesful with OpenAL (Alut is not available in Mac) and couldn't make sfml and SDL work on my system. So I decided to try Apple's PlayFile example:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PlayFile/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008651

I can play sounds using this example. However, when a sound starts playing, OpenGL freezes, namely all the animation stops until sound is done playing.

I checked the file PlayFile.cpp and found this line:

```
    usleep ((int)(fileDuration * 1000. * 1000.));
```

which I think is responsible for freezing OpenGL. Before this line, we start playing sound. After this line we clean up buffers. Is there any way that I can change the code, so that, sound starts playing, OpenGL continues its tasks, once sound is done playing we clean the buffers? I tried to use other solutions like pointers, to clean up after playing started, but now I can not make any sound out of the app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after days of research I found a way to fix this problem. I used pthread to create multiple threads, one for each sound. I just added

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

to any file that defines a thread. I defined a list for my sounds and threads:

```
pthread_t threads[3];
string sounds[3] = {"back.wav", "Arrow1.wav", "Arrow2.wav"};
```

And used a simple function:

```
void * playSound(void *threadid)
{
long tid;
tid = (long)threadid;
player(sounds[tid], 1);
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

that plays a sound when I create a thread:

```
pthread_create(&threads[2], NULL, playSound, (void *)2);
```

This way my animation can be combined with sound easily.

Comment: +1 : I find it very nice of you to come back with the answer you found and share it =)

Comment: This is reasonable if you work with plain playback of simple sounds. Yet, "PlayFile"  is a complete command line application (whose link is now dead) lays itself on CoreAudio, which has a very powerful _non-blocking_ real-time thread, and whose real-time callback shouldn't interfere with OpenGL. So, getting your OpenGL drawing blocked has nothing to do with CoreAudio, it has to do with how "PlayFile" is made.